# Skip over lines that cause errors in PostgreSQL Copy Command

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I get a UTF encoding error when trying to copy data from a csv file

```
Error invalid by sequence for encoding...
SQL State: 22021 
Context Copy mydatabase line 165
```

I am wondering if it is possible to skip over the line(s) that throws the error. I am aware that is possible to skip the first line using the `header` command but the line I get isn't in the first row. I'd like to find a solution inside of Postgres rather than one that has me going into another program.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, [that functionality hasn't been integrated into PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Error_logging_in_COPY#History). The quickest workaround I know of is to use sed to filter out bad input lines. If you really must keep the solution PostgreSQL-based, I know of no alternative to using PL/pgsql or another procedural language interface to read in your data.

Answer (score 2):

You could use PGLoader, a data loading tool for PostgreSQL. 
The COPY command is a single transaction so either all the data will get imported or none of it will.
PGLoader has a transaction behaviour, it will keep a separate file of rejected data, but continue trying to copy good data in your database.

Here the repository:
https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader